# how to append table to DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a table to `div`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addStuff() {
                var html = '<table>';
                $.each(function() {
                        html += '<tr><td>' + '</td></tr>';
                        });
                html += '</table>';
                $("#divResults").append(html);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divResults"></div>
        <button onclick="addStuff()">Add Stuff</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it is not working. I want to dynamically add table to the DIV block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to append table to the DIV try this....

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addTable() 

{
    $('#divResults').append('<table width="320" border="1"><tr><td colspan="2" rowspan="1">' + " wdw" + '</td></tr><tr><td width="118">' + "sxs" + '</td><td width="186">' + "xs" + '</td></tr></table>');
}

    </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <div id="divResults">
    </div>
    <button onclick="addTable()">Add Stuff</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6):

`each` what?  Your `$.each` method needs to loop over something. e.g.

```js
function addStuff() {
  var words = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  var html = '<table>';

  $.each(words, function(i, word) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + word + '</td></tr>';
  });

  html += '</table>';

  $("#divResults").append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divResults"></div>
<button onclick="addStuff()">Add Stuff</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `$.each()` but not passing any collection for it to iterate.

```
 // ---v---no collection?
$.each(function() {
    html += '<tr><td>' + '</td></tr>';
});
```

Normally you'd pass an Array or something.

```
$.each(["foo", "bar", "baz"], function(i, val) {
    html += '<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>';
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/VLfvv/

---

Note that this is a little different from the `.each()` method, which operates on a jQuery object, so the members of the object become the value.

```
$(".foobar").each(function(i, el) {
    // do something with the element
});
```

---

Also note that if all you want is to add this empty table, it could easily be done without jQuery.

```
function addStuff() {
    var html = '<table>';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        html += '<tr><td>' + '</td></tr>';

    html += '</table>';

    document.getElementById("divResults")
            .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
}
```

- [MDN docs: `element.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
var myTable = document.createElement("img");

var row1 = gameGrid.insertRow(0);
var row2 = gameGrid.insertRow(1);

var col1 = row1.insertCell(0);
var col2 = row2.insertCell(1);

col1.innerText = "some thing";

document.getElementById("divResults").innerHtml = myTable;
```